# Need help rewriting a T-SQL query for results to get displayed in a stacked bar

Tags: t-sql

I have come up with the following query which gives rise to the below result.

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT s.UserfName AS ASSIGNEE, e.status, COUNT(*) AS [TOTAL COUNT], CASE WHEN e.status = "Open" THEN 'OPEN' END AS 
FROM            dbo.t_helpdesktickets AS e INNER JOIN
                         dbo.t_assetusers AS s ON e.currentlyat = s.UserID
WHERE        (e.status IN ('open', 'closed'))
GROUP BY s.UserfName, e.status
```

[image]

How will I rewrite my query to return results as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    s.UserfName AS ASSIGNEE,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN e.status = 'open' THEN 1 END) AS "OPEN",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN e.status = 'closed' THEN 1 END) AS "CLOSED"
FROM dbo.t_assetusers AS s
LEFT JOIN dbo.t_helpdesktickets AS e
    ON e.currentlyat = s.UserID
GROUP BY
    s.UserfName;
```

Note that I switched to using a left join here, in case certain users might not have any records corresponding to either of the two statuses.  Using this approach, the open/closed counts would then show up as zero.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks.